# K means loop doesn't work for the image clustering

Tags: python, image, google-colaboratory, image-classification

I am using the code in Study 2A in this link (https://github.com/yilangpeng/image-clustering/tree/main/study2A). In the D kmeans clustering, I met some problems because I need assign every label from k means to every picture, but the number of label is 9, the picture is 200, they are not matching well. The following is my code and error information.

```
import joblib, os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import ypoften as of

cwd = os.path.join('/content/drive/MyDrive/study2A/for lab teaching',"")
# please change this to the folder that has all the images

cvmodels = ["vgg16 fc1"]
## cvmodels = ["vgg16 fc1","vgg16 places fc1","vggface fc6"] choose the model you used
clmethod = "KMeans"

for cvmodel in cvmodels:

    features_savepath = os.path.join(cwd,'img exfeature1','features PCA',cvmodel+'.dat')
    features_array = joblib.load(features_savepath)
    X = pd.DataFrame(features_array)
    print(X)

    nd = 200
    X = X.iloc[:,0:nd]

    savefolder = cvmodel + ' ' + clmethod + ' PCA' + str(nd)

    # Read the 0321_imageselected_A.txt file
    imgnamefile = os.path.join(cwd, "0321_imageselected_A.txt")
    df = pd.read_csv(imgnamefile, sep='\t', header=0)

    for K in [2]:
        print('number of cluster', K)
        cl = KMeans(K, random_state=0)
        cl.fit(X)
        labels = cl.labels_

        imgnamefile = os.path.join(cwd,"0321_imageselected_A.txt")
        df = pd.read_csv(imgnamefile, sep ='\t', header = 0)
        print(df)

        df['label'] = labels
        filepath = os.path.join(cwd,'img cluster',savefolder,str(K),'label.txt')
        of.create_path(filepath)
        df.to_csv(filepath, index = None, header = None, sep = '\t')

    print("DONE"*20)
```

```
ValueError: Length of values (9) does not match length of index (200)
```

I want to have a txt file that includes label so that I can proceed following steps.